# foreach seemingly skips first array

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I'm using array_search with array_column to see if I can find a match between my two arrays, if so it should return the index of the array where the match was found which I can use to find their account number.

I'm having some trouble as for some reason it completely skips the first iteration (or seems to) and I have no idea why.

Array Structures:

```
$account = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Account number] => 100607
        [Account name] => Test User 1
        [Telephone] => 71
        [Contact Email address] => Test1@email.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Account number] => 101502
        [Account name] => Test User 2
        [Telephone] => 72
        [Contact Email address] => Test2@email.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Account number] => 101514
        [Account name] => Test User 3
        [Telephone] => 73
        [Contact Email address] => Test3@email.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Account number] => 125780
        [Account name] => Test User 4
        [Telephone] => 74
        [Contact Email address] => Test4@email.com
    )

) 
$multi_array = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test1@email.com
        [name] => Test User 1 
        [telephone] => 71
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test2@email.com
        [name] => Test User 2 
        [telephone] => 72
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test3@email.com
        [name] => Test User 3 
        [telephone] => 73
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test4@email.com
        [name] => Test User 4 
        [telephone] => 74
    )

)
```

My code:

```
function get_key($key,$phone_key,$name_key){    
if ($key == !false){
  return $key;
}if($phone_key == !false){
   return $phone_key;
}if($name_key == !false){
   return $name_key;
}else{
  return "";
}
}
$complete = array();
foreach ($multi_array as $array){

$key = array_search($array["email"], array_column($account, 'Contact Email address'),true);
$phone_key = array_search($array["telephone"], array_column($account, 'Telephone'),true);
$name_key = array_search($array["name"], array_column($account, 'Account name'),true);

$array['Account Number'] = $account[get_key($key,$phone_key,$name_key)]['Account number']; 

$complete[] = $array;

}
```

And the result of all that through print_r(); is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test1@email.com
        [name] => Test User 1 
        [telephone] => 71
        [Account Number] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test2@email.com
        [name] => Test User 2 
        [telephone] => 72
        [Account Number] => 101502
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test3@email.com
        [name] => Test User 3 
        [telephone] => 73
        [Account Number] => 101514
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => Test4@email.com
        [name] => Test User 4 
        [telephone] => 74
        [Account Number] => 125780
    )

)
```

It works as expected with the exception of the first array ['Account Number'] is left blank.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this : "($key == !false)"

Comment: You make a very good point, it should be ($key !== false), thus solving my problem!

Comment: I think you have another error. You are checking `$name_key` twice and `$phone_key` not at all.

Comment: My mistake! fixed it thanks @RST

Comment: Glad I could help :)